# How to place object in ROT

Tags: mfc, running-object-table

i went through this link http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2011/09/30/Running-Object-Table-and-NET.aspx
i want to know, can we place MFC object in RunningObjectTable or not. If yes how can we do that.

Please help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only COM objects can be placed in the ROT. MFC can be used to create a COM object, but it does not matter what language or library is used to implement the COM object.

Comment: Hi ScottMcp I have seen in some link ppl are saying that if we can create custom monikar for MFC control we can place MFC object in RunningObjectTable (ROT). Is it right? how can we create custom monikar for MFC

Comment: You can place an object into the ROT without a moniker.